# Is there a way to limit the HTTP response body size received by Dispatch?

Tags: scala, asynchttpclient, scala-dispatch

I'm using Dispatch to pull down a lot of pages from which I only need the first few K, and the pages are sometimes gigabytes.  Is there any way in scala-dispatch (dispatch/reboot), or maybe in the HTTP request, to truncate the body received?

(Context: I'm reading CSV files from public data sources, and am just trying to get the field names (header row) and one row of sample data.)

Answer (score 1):

You can using the [`>` handler](https://github.com/dispatch/reboot/blob/0.11.3/core/src/main/scala/handlers.scala#L16), which gives you access to the underlying [`com.ning.http.client.Response`](http://asynchttpclient.github.io/async-http-client/apidocs/com/ning/http/client/Response.html) instance. From there, it's simple:

```
import java.io._
import dispatch._, Defaults._
import com.ning.http.client.Response

def excerpt(bytes: Int) = {
  response: Response =>
    response.getResponseBodyExcerpt(100, "UTF-8")
}

def lines(count: Int) = {
  response: Response =>
    val stream = response.getResponseBodyAsStream
    val reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream))
    Stream.continually(reader.readLine()).take(count).toList
}

val u = url("http://stackoverflow.com/")
Http(u > excerpt(100)).onComplete(println)
Http(u > lines(2)).onComplete(println)
```

You might also try to request a smaller byte interval from the server using the [`Range` header](http://www.cyberciti.biz/cloud-computing/http-status-code-206-commad-line-test/). This requires server support, which can be tested using a `HEAD` request and then looking up the `Accept-Ranges: bytes` response header.